# Best database field type for CONTENT_LENGTH Http Header

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, http-headers

I would like to store the CONTENT_LENGTH http request header value in my SqlServer database.

What is the best database column datatype to store it? I was planning store it as a varchar( SIZE ).

I could handle it as BIGINT, max value = 9223372036854775807, but what I'm trying to do is store it as a varchar, in this case LENGTH(9223372036854775807) = 19, so varchar(19)  , is it ok?

Any help or idea about it?

Comment: _"I was planning store it as a varchar( SIZE )."_ - Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't be storing as `VARCHAR` type cause it's Numeric type.

As per `W3C RFC 2616-sec14.13` specification

> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the
>   entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in
>   the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would
>   have been sent had the request been a GET.
>
> An example is
>
> ```
>    Content-Length: 3495
> ```

You can see the full spec here [Content-Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

A look here for complete list of SQL Server supported data types [Data Types (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187752.aspx)

So essentially you should be storing as `INT` or `BIGINT` data type in SQL SERVER

Comment: @AlbertoMontellano, No it's not ok to store it as varchar. if it's numeric type then why store it as varchar? Moreover, if you do so then at some point while quering you will need to do unnecessary conversion/casting.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13), you could store it as a bigint since there is no upper limit to the size of the number that you can get. It would be good to also certify its > 0.

Comment: I could handle it as BIGINT, max value = 9223372036854775807, but what I'm trying to do is store it as varchar(20) , is it ok?